# trouble using fread in c

Tags: c, string, fread

Im having some trouble figuring out how to properly format fread statements. The below code is just some randomn stuff Im practicing with. Basically it fills information into the first array (s), writes 's' to a file, and then reads the file into the second array (s2). However I can't seem to get the fread statement formated in a way that doesnt give an error or return garbage. The arrays are in char datatype because, if my understanding is correct, char uses less memory than other datatypes. The eventual application of this practice code is for a data compression project.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

FILE *fp;
//file pointer

char s[56];
//first string

char s2[56];
//target string for the fread

int n=0;
//counting variable

int m=0;

int main (void)
{
    fp=fopen("test.bin", "w+");
    //open a file for reading and writing


    strcpy(s, "101010001101010");
    //input for the string

    for(n=0;n<56;n++)
    {
        if(s[n]==1)
            m=n;
        else if(s[n]==0)
            m=n;
    }
    printf("%d\n", m);
    //the above for loop finds how many elements in 's' are filled with 1's and 0's
    for(n=0;n<m;n++)
    {
        printf("%c", s[n]);
    }
    //for loop to print 's'


    fwrite(s, m, 1, fp);
    //writes 's' to the first file
    s2=fread(&s2, m, 1, fp);
    //an attempt to use fread...

    printf("\n\ns2\n\n");
    for(n=0;n<m;n++)
    {
        printf("%c", s2[n]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    //for loop to print 's2'
    fclose(fp);

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("press any number to close program\n");
    scanf("%d", &m);
}
```

Comment: First of all, in your first `for` loop, you are checking characters against integers. Try `if(s[n] == '1' || s[n] == '0') m=n;`

Comment: Every one of your 'global' variables should be inside the main function.  Avoid using globals whenever possible (use them when they're necessary, but only if they're necessary).  With a single function using them, they can all be local to `main()`.

Comment: You should also check that the `fopen()` call succeeded before using `fp`.  You should really check the return values from `fread()` in particular (but also `fwrite()`) to be sure that what you requested to be read or written actually was.  Nominally, you should check `fclose()` too; it might be the only time you get the 'out of disk space' error if you wrote so little data that it was all buffered until then.  However, you'd be in a majority not checking that.

Comment: you should put the comment BEFORE the code that is commented, or at the end of the line, but not in the next line.

Comment: Thankyou all for the comments. I'm pretty new to programming and all the feedback was very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

A FILE structure has an implicit seek position within the file.  You read and write from that seek position.  If you want to read what you have written, you need to change the seek position back to the beginning of the file with a call to [`fseek()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/).  In fact, for a file open for reading and writing, you must call `fseek()` when switching between reading and writing.

Comment: And between writing and reading, which catches people out if they're using a loop.  You need two positioning calls each iteration of a read/write (or write/read) loop.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of the `fread` function is of type `size_t`. It is the number of elements successfully read. (reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/)

Don't assign it to s2. Simply use `fread(&s2, m, 1, fp);`

Comment: More to the point, compare the result with the number of expected items (1) to ensure that the read operation worked.